# Prove: For any sequence of linearly independent elements $y_j \in X$ and $a_j \in \mathbb R$ there exists an element $f \in X^*$ s.t. $f(y_j)=a_j$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm trying to solve the following problem but I have no clue how to do it.

Let $(X,||.||)$ be a normed $\mathbb C$-vector space. Prove: For any sequence of linearly independent elements $y_j, 1 \leq j \leq N$, in $X$ and any sequence $(a_j)_{1 \leq j \leq N}$ in $\mathbb R$ there exists an element $f \in X^*$ s.t. $f(y_j)=a_j$ for any $1 \leq j \leq N$.

The only thing I know is that I need at some point the Hahn-Banach Theorem. I would be grateful if someone could help me to prove this statement.
Thanks!

Comment: What is $X^\ast$? The space of linear functionals? It's probably standard notation, I just can't remember offhand.

Comment: $X^*$ is the dual space of X, i.e. the space of all continuous linear maps from $X$ to $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Let $V'$ be the finite dimensional subspace generated by the $N$ independent vectors. You know that any assignment of images in $\mathbb C$ to these vectors determines a linear map from $V'\to \mathbb C$, right? Then you can probably work to apply the Hahn-Banach theorem to extend this. I don't remember how it works well enough to attempt it myself.

Comment: Hmm .. Hahn-Banach is something about extending linear functionals, right?  Perhaps Tiger should try using it that way.

Comment: So, I should try to take a finite dimensional subspace with N basis vectors (as they are all linearly independent) and map it to $\mathbb C$ ? And then trying to use the Hahn-Banach to extend the functionals s.t. it is true for any sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you learned about finite-dimensional spaces along the way. If you have a linearly independent set of vectors $\{ y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_N \}$, then the linear space $Y_N$ spanned by these is a finite-dimensional space. So there are linear functionals $f_j$ on $Y_N$ such that $f_j(y_k)=\delta_{j,k}$. Using these you can find a functional $f$ on $Y_N$ such that $f(y_j)=a_j$ (in fact $f=\sum_{j=1}^{N}a_jf_j$ is such a functional.)

The space $Y_N$ is a finite-dimensional normed space, inheriting its norm from $X$. All norms on a finite-dimensional space are equivalent. So the following norm is equivalent to the the induced one:
$$
              \|x\|_{1}=\sum_{j=1}^{N}|f_j(x)|
$$
Therefore, there is a constant $C$ such that $\|x\|_1 \le C\|x\|$ for all $x\in Y_N$, which forces the $f_j$ to be continuous with
$$
                  |f_j(x)| \le \|x\|_{1} \le C\|x\|.
$$
So $f$ is continuous on $Y_N$ with $|f(x)| \le (C\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_j|)\|x\|$ for all $x\in Y_N$. By the Hahn-Banach theorem you can extend $f$ to all of $X$ in such a way that $\|f\|_{X^*} \le C\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_j|$. Any such extension $\tilde{f}\in X^*$ satisfies $\tilde{f}(y_j)=a_j$ for $1 \le j \le N$.

Comment: Oh thanks, that makes sense to me. But I have a small question: Does it even matter if the normed vector space is $/mathbb R$ or $/mathbb C$ ? Of course, I have to take the complex version of the Hahn-Banach. But is there any other thing I have to be careful about?

Comment: @TigerLa : I don't think anything in my answer requires the underlying field to be real, provided you use the complex version of Hahn-Banach, as you mentioned.